# PyTorch RuntimeError: Device Mismatch in Custom Training Loop Despite Consistent Device Usage

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm working on a custom PyTorch model for a text-to-audio generation task using a diffusion model architecture. My setup involves processing text with a BERT model to generate embeddings, which are then used to condition audio generation. Despite explicitly moving all tensors and models to the same device (cuda if available, otherwise cpu), I'm encountering a RuntimeError indicating a device mismatch during training.

Here's a simplified version of my setup:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import librosa
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel

# Custom dataset class
class TextAudioDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, audio_dir, text_dir, tokenizer, bert_model, device):
        self.audio_dir = audio_dir
        self.text_dir = text_dir
        self.files = os.listdir(audio_dir)
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.bert_model = bert_model.to(device)
        self.device = device

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.files)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # Code to load and process audio and text files
        # Returns text_embeddings.to(self.device), audio_tensor.to(self.device)

# Custom model, including a U-Net with FiLM layers conditioned on text embeddings
class DiffusionModel(nn.Module):
    # Model initialization and methods

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased').to(device)
dataset = TextAudioDataset('./wavs', './transcripts', tokenizer, bert_model, device)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True)

# Model and training setup
diffusion_model = DiffusionModel(...).to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(diffusion_model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

def train(model, dataloader, optimizer, epochs=10, device=device):
    model.train()
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for i, (text_embeddings, audio) in enumerate(dataloader):
            text_embeddings = text_embeddings.to(device)
            audio = audio.to(device)
            # Forward pass, loss calculation, backward pass, and optimizer step

train(diffusion_model, dataloader, optimizer, epochs=10, device=device)
```

Despite moving all tensors (text_embeddings, audio) and models (bert_model, diffusion_model) to the intended device, I'm still getting the following error during training:

```
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
```

I've double-checked that every tensor and model is explicitly moved to device before any operation that involves them. Could there be any part of my setup or approach that I'm overlooking which could cause this device mismatch issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to see from this snippet of code. I have had a similar issue before with custom models. When your custom model consists of multiple parts, I have found that it is sometimmes necesary to move the individual parts to the device so lets say you have model A that combines an LSTM model B with a CNN model C, than you do

```
B.to(device)
C.to(device)
```

Instead of `A.to(device)`
. It is worth a try if this is the case for you. Otherwise you need to debug by leaving out certain groups of tensors/models to find which part of the code introduces the cpu tensor